# How to solve the functional equation $f(x+a)=f(x)+a$

Tags: functional-equations

Are there any other solutions of the functional equation $f(x+a)=f(x)+a$ ($a=\mathrm{const}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$) apart from $f(x)=x+C$ ($C=\mathrm{const}$)?

**Edit:** $a$ is a fixed number here.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: is this supposed to hold for one particular $a$, or for all $a$ ?

Comment: @Mirko For one particular $a$ and for all $x$.

Comment: See http://www.ijmex.com/index.php/ijmex/article/view/194 for its general solution on arbitrary groups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are continuous functions apart from $x+C$.

Given $a\not=0$ let $f(x)=x+\sin(\dfrac{2\pi x}{a})$.

Then $f(x+a)=x+a+\sin(\dfrac{2\pi (x+a)}{a})=x+a+\sin(\dfrac{2\pi x}{a}+2\pi)= x+\sin(\dfrac{2\pi x}{a}) +a=f(x)+a$.

As indicated in another answer you may get many other (discontinuous) functions by partitioning the reals. But you may also get many continuous functions, following the above model using any continuous periodic function with period $a$.

Comment: Nice! Showed what I wrote was not entirely correct.

Answer (score 4):

No if the equation holds for all $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. The functional equation $f(x + a) = f(x) + a$ implies that
$$\frac{f(x + a) - f(x)}{a} = 1.$$
Taking the limit of both sides as $a \to 0$ shows that $f'$ exists and $f'(x) = 1$, so the only solutions are $f(x) = x + C$. as you stated.

Comment: isn't $a$ fixed?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if OP meant for $a$ to be fixed or for the equation to hold for all $a \neq 0$.

Comment: $a$ is fixed, $x$ is not.

Comment: if $a\not=0$ if fixed, then the answer is yes

Answer (score 2):

(This is with the understanding that $f(x + a) = f(x) + a$ is true for some fixed $a$, but all $x$.)

There are many solutions, with very poor behavior.

If you call $x$ and $y$ equivalent if $x = na + y$ for some integer $n$, then you can partition $\mathbb{R}$ into the equivalence classes. Pick a representative $x$ from each equivalence class $[x]$ and define $f(x)$ to be whatever you like, then extend to the rest of the equivalence classes using the defining equation $f(y) = f(na + x) = f(x) + na$.

Riffing off Mirko slightly, you can think about it this way. You can define $f$ however you like on the interval, say, $[0,a)$ (assuming $a>0$). Then define $f$ on $[a,2a)$ by $f(y) = f(x+ a) = f(x) + a$ for the unique $x\in[0,1)$ with $x+a = y$, and continue inductively.

Comment: That is right, so you get discontinuous as well as continuous functions this way: To get continuous ones you need to start with a continuous $f$ on $[0,a)$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to a^-}=f(0)+a$. Equivalently, start with a continuous $f$ on $[0,a]$ satisfying $f(a)=f(0+a)=f(0)+a$, and then extend as indicated.

Comment: Indeed. $f$ being continuous on $[0,a)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} = f(0) +a$ is both necessary and sufficient to get $f$ continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The given equation is equivalent to $g(x+a)=g(x)$ where $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Take any periodic function g with period a and take $f(x)$ to be $g(x)+x$. This gives a complete solution to your question.